# How can my tiny fey (custom race) PC avoid drowning in her potion of healing?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, healing, creature-size

My husband is the DM, and he made a custom race for me — a tiny fey. The only problem is the the size of a Potion of Cure Light Wounds: it would be a bathtub for me, due to being 8 inches tall. We were thinking of quick drink/swift drink feat/rage power for barbarians, but I am a rogue.

How can I drink a cure light wounds potion without being bloated and/or dying from the potion itself?

Is there a way to get tiny potions that can do the same thing for a tiny person?

Comment: Related: [How much does a potion weigh?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/51573/how-much-do-scrolls-and-potions-weigh)

Comment: Note that an 8 inch creature is technically in the Diminutive category. http://d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/

Comment: Hey all - we don't do list questions/brainstorms here on RPG.SE.  I'm sorry some answers are being downvoted, but it's because they are not answering the question, and are instead providing "a neat idea."

Comment: I misread "Tina Fey Custom Race" in the Hot Network Questions area. Not disappointed that I clicked it.

Comment: Just a reminder: The comments aren't the place for chatting about the hypothetical situation, asking new questions, or suggesting solutions. For that stuff we have [chat], the Ask button, and the Answer button, respectively. Thanks!

Comment: Get out your tiny fey frying pan, and make a reduction sauce out of it.  ;)

Answer (score 33):

The [rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems.html) read

> When an article of magic clothing or jewelry is discovered, most of the time size shouldn’t be an issue. Many magic garments are made to be easily adjustable, or they adjust themselves magically to the wearer. **Size should not keep characters of various kinds from using magic items.**
>
> There may be rare exceptions, especially with racial specific items.

You see, the rules insist that any character should be able to use most magic items. Size should not be an issue.

How you narrate it is up to you and the DM. Either you say the potion magically shrinks to appropriate size, or only a small portion of the liquid is sufficient to make the magic work (and the rest of the liquid nonmagical), your variant. Rules are not made to limit your imagination, only to make the game properly balanced. Just make sure that the effect of the potion does not change.

Comment: Note that even if only a small portion of the liquid is necessary, it should probably still consume the entire potion, or at least render the rest inert.

Comment: @KRyan I meant that, but you are right, it may not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56934/discussion-on-answer-by-ols-how-can-my-tiny-fey-custom-race-pc-avoid-drowning).

Answer (score 25):

## Potions in *Pathfinder* may be littler than initially imagined

Popular culture frequently depicts magic potions as being of significant quantity. A Medium creature hears *magic potion* and may imagine something like this:

[image: Original image available at https://www.shutterstock.com/video/search/magic-potion] 
<sup>***Chug! Chug! Chug!***</sup>

However, in *Pathfinder*, the ["typical potion or oil consists of 1 ounce of liquid held in a ceramic or glass vial fitted with a tight stopper. The stoppered container is usually no more than 1 inch wide and 2 inches high."](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/potions/) So when a Medium creature actually *gets* that magic potion, he ends up with something closer to this:

[image: Original image available through https://www.tumblr.com/search/danger%20mysteries] <sup>***Swig, I guess?***</sup>

[Only the littlest of Fine creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates/) could bathe in a *Pathfinder* potion vial!

### The rules want creatures of *all* sizes drinking potions

Like this fine [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/97875/8610) mentions, the game would have most magic items *not* be significantly restricted due to a creature's size.

Thus a Tiny, Diminutive, or Fine creature in *Pathfinder* has no special rules for potion consumption despite the creature's size. Likewise, a Huge, Gargantuan,  or Colossal creature, for example, does not fumble with the itty-bitty potion bottle nor does it find itself less affected by the potion for having consumed, by comparison, only a drop.

As long as a creature "removes the stopper and swallows the potion," the magic potion will take effect normally. *How much* needs to be consumed is where the GM fits into this equation, but ruling that a creature consumes *enough* of the potion to activate the magic and this leaves the undrunk portion of the potion nonmagical seems a reasonable enough nod to magical verisimilitude (oxymoron notwithstanding).

Note that some creatures just can't use potions. Creatures that are incorporeal, for instance, are specifically barred from using potions, as are creatures affected by the spell [*iron body*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/iron-body/), but, since nothing stops even a [skeleton](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/skeleton/) from benefiting from a magic potion, a Tiny creature that possesses both lips and a belly should have no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The potion could be sized according to the size of the creature using it and you could say something along the lines of bigger creatures needing more potion because they have more blood to dilute it. So instead of having a normal-sized portion of healing potion it could be scaled down to fit your fairy character.